# sum of multiple column in last row particular columns seperatly

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my table :

```
id  positive  positive2  positive3  positive4  negative  negative2  negative3  
---  ---------  ---------  ---------  --------  ---------  ---------  -----------
1      6          0          0          0         0          1          3
```

I take a positives count from last row by using below query :

```
SELECT SUM(positive + positive2 + positive3 + positive4 ) AS positive`chartdata` 
FROM chartdata 
GROUP BY id DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

I got this as a output :

### positive

6

I need to get the negatives also through one query can anyone help me.

Comment: Sum and group by do nothing here. If you were to amend your schema to have 3 columns instead of 8, then sum and group by would have a valid role to play

Comment: DESC is useless with group by, you should use ORDER BY instead. Also, the SUM function isn't needed, just add the columns. You would do the same for the "negative" columns.

Comment: could you give the solution as a query i am new to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got the answer for my question thanks for all reply me

```
    SELECT positive + positive2 + positive3 + positive4 AS positive,
negative + negative2 + negative3 + negative4 AS negative FROM chartdata ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

> this is the query for that

Comment: Great. Now consider normalising your schema

Comment: now i want to update this into another table which has a positive and negative as a column

Answer (score -1):

**query**

```
select id, SUM(positive1 + positive2 + positive3) as positive, SUM(negative1 + negative2) as negative from chart_data group by id order by id desc;
```

**For detailed information please refer below image**

[image]